# Random get_template_part in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, random

I'm looking for a way to show four template parts in a random order. They're arranged in a 2x2 grid and I need the order to be different every time the page loads. Here's the code:

```
<!-- Feature 1 -->
      <div class="grid_half">
        <?php get_template_part( 'features/feat','1' ); //Get Features Section 1 ?>
    </div><!-- /.grid_half -->
<!-- Feature 2 -->
      <div class="grid_half_last"> 
        <?php get_template_part( 'features/feat','2' ); //Get Features Section 2 ?>
     </div><!-- /.grid_half_last -->
      <div class="clear"></div>
<!-- Feature 3 -->
      <div class="grid_half"> 
        <?php get_template_part( 'features/feat','3' ); //Get Features Section 3 ?>
      </div><!-- /.grid_half -->
<!-- Feature 4 -->
      <div class="grid_half_last">
        <?php get_template_part( 'features/feat','4' ); //Get Features Section 4 ?>
      </div><!-- /.grid_half_last -->
      <div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working for me:

```
    <?php $features = array('1', '2', '3', '4'); 
        shuffle($features); ?>
<!-- Feature 1 -->
      <div class="grid_half">
        <?php get_template_part( 'features/feat', $features[0] ); //Get Features Section 1 ?>
    </div><!-- /.grid_half -->
<!-- Feature 2 -->
      <div class="grid_half_last"> 
        <?php get_template_part( 'features/feat', $features[1] ); //Get Features Section 2 ?>
     </div><!-- /.grid_half_last -->
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <!-- Feature -->
      <div class="grid_half"> 
        <?php get_template_part( 'features/feat', $features[2] ); //Get Features Section 3 ?>
      </div><!-- /.grid_half -->
<!-- Feature -->
      <div class="grid_half_last">
        <?php get_template_part( 'features/feat', $features[3] ); //Get Features Section 4 ?>
      </div><!-- /.grid_half_last -->
      <div class="clear"></div>
```

Files are named feat-1.php, feat-2.php etc. in a subfolder named features in the interests of full info.

Answer (score 2):

```
$order = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
shuffle($order);
```

Then:

```
get_template_part( 'features/feat', array_shift($order) );
```

To ensure you don't get the same order within 4 consecutive page requests, you'll have to keep track of this array, perhaps trough sessions or client cookies.

Comment: he could also store the current template number as a session variable and upon the next page load remove that number from the array

Comment: `<?php $features = array('1', '2', '3', '4'); 
  shuffle($features); ?><?php get_template_part( 'features/feat', $features[0] ); //Get Features Section 1 ?>` Soon as I posted I got it. Thanks for your help guys